# Mix array with ancestor elements

Tags: php, arrays

Seems to be very simple but I'm like, losing a lot of time on this... and no success...

If I have a string:

```
$str = "She sells seashells"
```

So I turn every word into an array element

```
$array = explode(" ", $str);
```

What I need is, every word receive the ancestor element (if any) and the next ones...

Example result in json format (more easy to show)

```
"{"She":["sells","seashells"],"sells":["She","seashells"],"seashells":["She","sells"]}"
```

Can somebody help?

Thanks!

Comment: That example seems rather ambiguous. What exactly do you mean by “ancestor”, just the immediately preceding word? Would still not explain why the last entry should be `"seashells":["She","sells"]`

Comment: How does that work with more than three words?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Really, you can copy a source array for each key, excluding that key:

```
$str = "She sells seashells";
$array = explode(" ", $str);

$res = [];
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    $res[$array[$i]] = $array;
    unset($res[$array[$i]][$i]);
}

print_r($res);
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8accad0222eb6a7dbcaac76a93f8b7fe7dfdbeca)

Comment: Haha amazing! Thank you so much!! :D

Comment: Using unset is impressive

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$str = "She sells seashells";

$arr = explode(" ",$str);
$length = count($arr);
$result = [];

for($i = 0;$i < $length;++$i){
    $result[$arr[$i]] = [];
    foreach ($arr as $each_val) {
        if($each_val === $arr[$i]) continue;
        $result[$arr[$i]][] = $each_val;
    }
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{"She":["sells","seashells"],"sells":["She","seashells"],"seashells":["She","sells"]}
```

- Explode the string based on spaces.
- Have a `result` array and make the current iteration value in for loop as the key for it.
- Loop again over the array and check if current value matches with outer for loop value. If yes, then continue, else add that value in this `result` array key.
- In the end, [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) it and you are done.

Comment: @jbyrd Can you give an example? OP doesn't mention anything about duplicacy, but I would fix it if there's an issue.

Comment: You're right - after reading the code more closely and testing it, it does work. Upvote.

Comment: @jbyrd Thanks. Cheers :)